# How can I know if netcat & dd are working?

Tags: linux, dd, netcat

I'm running on server A (Source):

```
dd bs=16M if=/dev/sda|bzip2 -c|nc serverB.example.net 19000
```

On server B (Destination):

```
nc -l -p 19000|bzip2 -d|dd bs=16M of=/dev/sdb
```

Do I need to see some progress somewhere? (Server's A /dev/sda is 50GB)

I've been waiting for 20 minutes, still both are running, how can I know that its really transferring data / etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send the `dd` process a `USR1` signal:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null &
[1] 977
$
$ kill -USR1 977
274647+0 records in
274646+0 records out
140618752 bytes (141 MB) copied, 17.3286 s, 8.1 MB/s
$
```

Comment: I usually do `killall -USR1 dd`

Answer (score 8):

¿have you tried pv? http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

```
dd bs=16M if=/dev/sda|bzip2 -c| pv | nc serverB.example.net 19000
nc -l -p 19000| pv | bzip2 -d| dd bs=16M of=/dev/sdb
```

good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Find the PID of the process that you want to check the I/O for in your case the `dd` on server b would be a good place to look then

```
cat /proc/<PID>/io
```

look at the value for `wchar` which should be the bytes written value.

For future reference you can insert [**pv**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) into one (or both) of the pipes and it will tell you how much data has passed through it.

```
dd bs=16M if=/dev/sda|bzip2 -c|pv|nc serverB.example.net 19000
225MB 0:04:48 [ 799kB/s] [                    <=>                            ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the man page for dd on your OS, but is should support a USR1 signal which will give you a progress check. If you know the pid of you process, just send it a "kill -USR1 $pid" and it will show you how far it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iftop` to see network traffic or `iotop` to see IO usage.

Answer (score 0):

`watch -d -n 1 ifconfig` on server B. It will highlight all received traffic (RX packets/bytes). Don't count on the accuracy of the values if you're using a 32-bit distribution (you still can see if it's still working).

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of `dd` in GNU-Coreutils (>8.24) now include a `status` argument, to avoid all the `pv` and `USR1` signal hacks:

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress`

If on a Mac:

```
brew install coreutils
# All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'
gdd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress
```